# What is a rollback?

Tags: support, editing

What is the rollback feature on the TeX forum?

Comment: Do you mean the 'rollback' link when you look at the editing history of a question or answer?

Comment: Well, I wasn't sure to be honest. I just saw a reference to the term here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/badges It says that if you do a 'rollback', you get the 'Cleanup' badge.

Comment: Also see the same question on [metase]: [What is a 'rollback'?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17038/what-is-a-rollback)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may use the "rollback" link in the editing history of a post to revert the post to this version. This is useful when you think certain edits are so flawed that they should be not used as a starting point for further edits, but simply undone.

Comment: @User17670 The link "edited" leads to a post#s editing history.